# deploy rails app that uses devise on heroku with mongohq

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, heroku, devise, ruby-on-rails-3.2

my app uses devise and mongo so i added mongohq as an addon but when it try to open my app on heroku i get this error :

> An error occurred in the application and your page could not be
>   served. Please try again in a few moments.
>
> If you are the application owner, check your logs for details.

heroku log :

```
2014-05-23T14:58:38.601715+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/mongo-1.10.1/lib/mongo/mongo_client.rb:422:in `connect': Failed to connect to a master node at localhost:27017 (Mongo::ConnectionFailure)
2014-05-23T14:58:38.580675+00:00 app[web.1]: There is a configuration error with the current mongoid.yml.
2014-05-23T14:58:38.580684+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2014-05-23T14:58:38.580686+00:00 app[web.1]: Problem:
2014-05-23T14:58:38.580688+00:00 app[web.1]:   No sessions configuration provided.
2014-05-23T14:58:38.580690+00:00 app[web.1]: Summary:
2014-05-23T14:58:38.580692+00:00 app[web.1]:   Mongoid's configuration requires that you provide details about each session that can be connected to, and requires in the sessions config at least 1 default session to exist.
2014-05-23T14:58:38.580693+00:00 app[web.1]: Resolution:
2014-05-23T14:58:38.580695+00:00 app[web.1]:   Double check your mongoid.yml to make sure that you have a top-level sessions key with at least 1 default session configuration for it. You can regenerate a new mongoid.yml for assistance via `rails g mongoid:config`.
2014-05-23T14:58:38.580697+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2014-05-23T14:58:38.580698+00:00 app[web.1]:  Example:
2014-05-23T14:58:38.580700+00:00 app[web.1]:    development:
2014-05-23T14:58:38.580701+00:00 app[web.1]:      sessions:
2014-05-23T14:58:38.580703+00:00 app[web.1]:        default:
2014-05-23T14:58:38.580704+00:00 app[web.1]:          database: mongoid_dev
```

here's my mongoid.yml:

```
development:
  # Configure available database sessions. (required)
  sessions:
    # Defines the default session. (required)
    default:
      # Defines the name of the default database that Mongoid can connect to.
      # (required).
      database: healthy_grocery_development
      # Provides the hosts the default session can connect to. Must be an array
      # of host:port pairs. (required)
      hosts:
        - localhost:27017
      options:
        # Change whether the session persists in safe mode by default.
        # (default: false)
        # safe: false

        # Change the default consistency model to :eventual or :strong.
        # :eventual will send reads to secondaries, :strong sends everything
        # to master. (default: :eventual)
        # consistency: :eventual

        # How many times Moped should attempt to retry an operation after
        # failure. (default: 30)
        # max_retries: 30

        # The time in seconds that Moped should wait before retrying an
        # operation on failure. (default: 1)
        # retry_interval: 1
  # Configure Mongoid specific options. (optional)
  options:
    # Configuration for whether or not to allow access to fields that do
    # not have a field definition on the model. (default: true)
    # allow_dynamic_fields: true

    # Enable the identity map, needed for eager loading. (default: false)
    # identity_map_enabled: false

    # Includes the root model name in json serialization. (default: false)
    # include_root_in_json: false

    # Include the _type field in serializaion. (default: false)
    # include_type_for_serialization: false

    # Preload all models in development, needed when models use
    # inheritance. (default: false)
    # preload_models: false

    # Protect id and type from mass assignment. (default: true)
    # protect_sensitive_fields: true

    # Raise an error when performing a #find and the document is not found.
    # (default: true)
    # raise_not_found_error: true

    # Raise an error when defining a scope with the same name as an
    # existing method. (default: false)
    # scope_overwrite_exception: false

    # Skip the database version check, used when connecting to a db without
    # admin access. (default: false)
    # skip_version_check: false

    # User Active Support's time zone in conversions. (default: true)
    # use_activesupport_time_zone: true

    # Ensure all times are UTC in the app side. (default: false)
    # use_utc: false
test:
  sessions:
    default:
      database: healthy_grocery_test
      hosts:
        - localhost:27017
      options:
        consistency: :strong
        # In the test environment we lower the retries and retry interval to
        # low amounts for fast failures.
        max_retries: 1
        retry_interval: 0
production:
  sessions:
    default:
      uri: <%= ENV['MONGOHQ_URL'] %>
      options:
        skip_version_check: true
        safe: true
```

Comment: Doesn't heroku overwrite that file?

Comment: @MichaelSzyndel in order to make heroku work i added the production part